# Calling keyDown: for items in an NSCollectionView

Tags: cocoa, keydown, nscollectionview

I have a problem to make the `keyDown:` method run for each item in an `NSCollectionView` when I press a key from the keyboard.

**Edit:** I have the next code in my NSCollectionViewItem but does't work, how can I do that specially make work the `acceptsFirstResponder`:

```
- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder
{
    [[[self view] window] makeFirstResponder:self];
    return YES;
}

- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent*)event
{
    NSString *chars = [event characters];
    unichar character = [chars characterAtIndex: 0];

    if(!sound){
        sound = [[NSSound alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:textFile.stringValue byReference:YES];
    }
    if ([checkButton state]==1) {
        [sound setLoops:YES];
    }else{
        [sound setLoops:NO];
    }
    if(character == (int)'w'){
        if ([sound isPlaying]){
            [sound stop];
            [sound release];
            sound = nil;
        } else {
            [sound play];
        }

    }
}
```

(Sorry for make a lot of changes is first question here)

Comment: Your question does not make sense in English. Can you try to rephrase?